# Payara MicroProfile 5.191 intermitted "converter not found" after clean, compile, package, run

Tags: jsf, converters, payara-micro

I've a Java EE 8 web project (war) with a JSF page that uses a converter.

When I try to load that page (after mvn clean compile package and java -jar payara-micro-5.191.jar --deploy rbooking.war) "sometimes" the converter class was not found.

To solve the problem the only solution is to recompile the war.

Here some details:

the pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sartorieinformatiche.it.rbooking</groupId>
  <artifactId>rbooking</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>prime-repo</id>
      <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
      <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>uaihebert.com</groupId>
      <artifactId>uaiCriteria</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>rbooking</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

the converter class:

```
package sartorieinformatiche.it.rbooking.control;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import sartorieinformatiche.it.rbooking.entity.Language;

@FacesConverter(value = "languageConverter", managed = true)
public class LanguageConverter implements Converter<Language> {

  @Inject
  private LanguageService languageService;

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Language language) {
    if (language == null) {
      return "";
    }

    return language.getId().toString();
  }

  @Override
  public Language getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }

    Long id = Long.parseLong(value);

    return languageService.findById(id);
  }

}
```

the JSF page fragment:

```
...<p:selectOneMenu id="language"
                 value="#{bookingBean.booking.language}"
                 converter="languageConverter">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bookingBean.allLanguages}"
                 itemLabel="#{language.description}"
                 itemValue="#{language.id}" />
    <p:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{language.description}" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>...
```

the error when the JSF page is loaded:

```
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: languageConverter not found.
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNullNamedObject(Util.java:467)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.InstanceFactory.createConverter(InstanceFactory.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:502)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createConverter(ApplicationWrapper.java:420)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.converter.ConverterManager.createConverter(ConverterManager.java:131)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.converter.ConverterManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.createConverter(Unknown Source)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.createConverter(OmniApplication.java:83)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$LiteralConverterMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:45)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:40)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:100)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:92)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:155)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:52)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:46)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:358)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

To solve the issue I have to recompile the project and the converter is correctly loaded...

Any idea to solve the issue ?

PS:
I'm using OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03) Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia.

Comment: JSF has nothing to do with compiling or creating the war, nor does your server and java-ee-8 is waaaay to broad. So how do you actually do create your war and compile things? Pure commandline maven?  IS the class actually not there when things fail?

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje, I've just tested again, the app now is running without errors, I've stopped it, modified a class inserting a comment, then I run clean and build from the IDE (NetBeans 11 runing on OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-3ubuntu116.04ppa1), the LanguageConverter.class was inserted into the war but running again I receive: javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: languageConverter not found, clean / build / run again and it works... I cannot understand what happens... (same problems with: mvn clean compile package)

Comment: Check if payara can/should be cleaned as well in between deploys so to prevent stale thing lingering around. Check if you have the same problem with another container (should  be not to difficult if you created a [mcve])

Comment: The problem seems located on payara micro, if I try to stop & run the server 20 times, 12 times it starts well and 8 times it starts wrong (languageConverter not found) (no recompilation at all)

Comment: Check for errors during deployment...

Comment: No errors during deployment...

Comment: Then try a newer (or older) version of Payara and check if it happens there and check the issuelist to see if it is related to a known issue

Comment: I've tried with payara-micro 5.182 / 5.183 / 5.184, the prolem is still here, so I've tried with payara full 5.191 inserting the war into autodeploy folder and the app works (I've tried to run & stop domain1 10 times, no error at all...), the problem is into payara micro distribution...

Comment: Maybe file an issue in their issuelist then...

Comment: Solved with 5.192 release

Comment: Please create an answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved on Payara Micro 5.192